# Bash: loop through files that DO NOT match extension

Tags: regex, bash, file, loops

I'm writing a bash script that needs to loop files inside a directory that do not match a specific extension. So far, I've found that the following code loops all files that matches the given extension:

```
for f in *.txt ; do
    echo $f;
done
```

How could insthead loop through files that do not match the specified extension?

Comment: you can use `^(.*[^\.txt])$`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pattern-match with the `==` operator.

```
for f in *; do
    [[ $f == *.txt ]] && continue
    # [[ $f != *.txt ]] || continue
    ...
done
```

If this might run in an empty directory, either use `shopt -s nullglob` prior to the loop, or put `[ -e "$f" ] || continue` in side the loop. (The former is preferable, as it avoids constantly checking if a file exists.)

Comment: And then just `[ -e "$f" ] || continue`

Comment: `[ -e "$f" ]` will always succeed, since `$f` was set via a pathname expansion.

Comment: @chepner ... unless there are no files for `*` to match

Comment: Well, sure, if you're worried about an empty directory :)

Comment: @chepner: it's bound to happen sooner or later.

Comment: My comment was a little too tongue-in-cheek; I agree it's a real concern.

Answer (score 6):

> to loop files inside a directory that do not match a specific extension

You can use `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob

for f in *.!(txt); do
    echo "$f"
done
```

pattern `*.!(txt)` will match all entries with a dot and no `txt` after the dot.

---

**EDIT:** Please see comments below. Here is a `find` version to loop through files in current directory that don't match a particular extension:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r f; do
    echo "$f"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name '*.txt' -print0)
```

Comment: `mkdir -p foo; touch foo/file.1.txt; shopt -s extglob; echo foo/*.!(txt)`

Comment: Yes I understand that. One can even create directories using DOT and that will also be found by this command. I think better to use `find -type f`. (see updated)

Comment: @anubhava yes, this one worked fine. I've also tested the solution proposed by chepner, and found that solution just a little more flexible.

Comment: ok just make sure sure to skip sub-directories as well inside `for` loop

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in !(*.txt) ; do
    echo $f
done
```

You just inverse the glob pattern using `!(glob_pat)`, and to use it, you need to enable extended glob.

If you want to ignore directories, then:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in !(*.txt) ; do
    [ -d "$f" ] && continue   # This will ignore dirs
    # [ -f "$f" ] && continue # This will ignore files
    echo $f
done
```

If you wanna go into all sub-dirs then:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
for f in !(*.txt) **/!(*.txt) ; do
    [ -d "$f" ] && continue   # This will ignore dirs
    # [ -f "$f" ] && continue # This will ignore files
    echo $f
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
find /path/to/look -type f -not -name "*.txt" -print0 | while read -r -d '' file_name
do
echo "$file_name"
done
```

when your filenames may be nonstandard.

**Note:**

If you don't wish to recursively search for files in subfolders include `-maxdepth 1`
 just before `-type f`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok for a `GNU` solution, give a try to this:

```
for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \! -name \*.txt) ; do
  printf "%s\n" "${f}"
done
```

This is going to break if special chars are contained in the filenames, such as  (space).

For something safe, still `GNU`, try:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \! -name \*.txt -printf "%p\0" | xargs -0 sh -c '
    for f ; do
      printf "%s\n" "${f}"
    done' arg0
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for f in $(ls --hide="*.txt")
do
    echo $f
done
```