# Searching through files except regex expression Shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell

i am not really advanced in shell programming and regular expressions. I need to ignore files which names matches the regular expressions. I've tried many things. This is my function:

```
for file in $1/*  <-------- This matches every file, i need it to ignore something stored in variable like: ARG="file.txt"
    do
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
            dir_count=$((dir_count+1))
            dir_file_counter $file
        fi
            #if file is directory then increment DIRCOUNT and recursively look into that directory
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
            det_size $file
            file_count=$((file_count+1))
        fi
    done
```

I've tried negative lookarounds, but that didn't help:
when i use argument like: arg="(!? text.txt).*"
It simply added that in to the adress and did not match anything.
Can somebody help?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash: loop through files that DO NOT match extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258673/bash-loop-through-files-that-do-not-match-extension)

Comment: If all you need to do is count the number of files recursively while excluding a pattern, you can use a combination of `find`, `grep -v` and `wc`. Something like `find path/to/search -type f | grep -v 'pattern_to_exclude' | wc -l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
find . ! -name '*.csv' ! -name '*.jpg'
```

And it will give you all the files except for those ending in something you choose.